# User defined type used in dynamic allocated 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator

Let's assume that we have a simple struct

```cpp
struct S {
     int a;
     int b;
     int c;
}
```

Now we want to create an array of pointers (2d array 5x5):

```cpp
S** arr = new S*[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    arr[i] = new S[5];
```

My questions are:

1. Is it a correct way to dynamically allocate a memory for this array using `new`? Shouldn't we use `sizeof(S)` somewhere?
2. How would the code look like if using `malloc` instead of `new`? Is the code below correct?

```cpp
S** arr = (S**)malloc(5 * sizeof(S));
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    arr[i] = (S*)malloc(5 * sizeof(S));
```

Comment: Stick a non-trivially-copyable member in `S`, and that `malloc` code fails miserably.

Comment: The *correct* way to dynamically allocate this array is `std::vector<std::vector<S>>`. Your `new` version falls under "technically working", and the `malloc` one under "undefined behaviour".

Comment: @OP This "simple struct" fails using `malloc`:  `struct S { std::string str; };`.  That one single `std::string` member renders the malloc code broken.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But I don't use `std::string` here.

Comment: @Quentin What is the issue here with `malloc`?

Comment: @Michal *Let's assume that we have a simple struct* -- But you do see how simple it is to break your `malloc` code?  C++ is not C -- Any non-trivially-copyable type renders the `malloc` code broken.  If your code were robust, you would have `if (std::is_trivially_copyable<S>()) { do the malloc code; }`.  The `is_trivially_copyable` comes from `#include <type_traits>`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Does the same issue exist with `new`?

Comment: The same issue does not exist with `new`, since `new` not only allocates memory, but it also constructs objects.  The `malloc` just allocates `n` bytes of memory, and that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, this is correct way. No, there is no need to use `sizeof(S)`
2. Your code isn't correct. Generally you shouldn't use `malloc` if `struct S` have non-trivially-copiable members, but if S satisfy that, your code should look like this:

```cpp
S** arr = (S**)malloc(5 * sizeof(S*));
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    arr[i] = (S*)malloc(5 * sizeof(S));
```

But using malloc in C++ is considered as bad practice. And I would try to rewrite it using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if you can.
And of course don't forget to clear memory with `delete`/`free` in case of using `new`/`malloc`

Comment: You really should mention that the `malloc` code is broken if `S` changes to have non-trivially-copyable members.